# How to use cURL to find the redirect location

Tags: curl, redirect

I was able to open the link: https://georgetown.app.box.com/s/32o25lslrx69q6n4n12egrd5yudswpl7. I know it was redirected to another URL if I wanted to download it by programming. But, when I run the cURL command line in Windows to find the request header:

```
curl -I https://georgetown.app.box.com/s/32o25lslrx69q6n4n12egrd5yudswpl7
```

I got the message: HTTP:/1.1 404 Not Found. Why is that? And how do I find where the redirect URL is?

Answer (score 1):

That request is not redirected to another location.

`curl -I` alone sends `HEAD` request, whereas `GET` is expected, and the server returns HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found. Switch `HEAD` to `GET` back:

```
curl -I -X GET https://georgetown.app.box.com/s/32o25lslrx69q6n4n12egrd5yudswpl7
```

The output

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 28 Jun 2022 17:41:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Set-Cookie: z=l18d51viefeqhavk2k2q74aja4; path=/; domain=.app.box.com; secure; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: z=l18d51viefeqhavk2k2q74aja4; Path=/; Domain=.app.box.com; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
Set-Cookie: box_visitor_id=62bb3d620316f4.90388524; expires=Wed, 28-Jun-2023 17:41:54 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/; domain=.box.com; secure
Set-Cookie: bv=OPS-45321; expires=Tue, 05-Jul-2022 17:41:54 GMT; Max-Age=604800; path=/; domain=.app.box.com; secure
Set-Cookie: cn=21; expires=Wed, 28-Jun-2023 17:41:54 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/; domain=.app.box.com; secure
Set-Cookie: site_preference=desktop; path=/; domain=.box.com; secure
```